# How to have Gitlab send requests to https url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, gitlab

I have an AWS ELB in charge of the https endpoint of my application. Each request on port 443 get redirected to port 80 of an Ubuntu 14.04 EC2 instance running Gitlab Omnibus version 8.10.4-ce.

In gitlab configuration (/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb), I define external_url with http scheme:

```
external_url "http://gitlab.mydomain.com"
```

Defining it with https scheme prevents nginx from starting as a crt is requested in Gitlab configuration.

Is there a way to tell GitLab to send request to ELB on https://gitlab.mydomain.com instead of http (as in this case, the ELB is the one in charge of the tls termination) ?

Comment: Please post exact details of your error messages. Please expand abbreviations such as "crt". You may just need to get an https certificate for your server. If your gitlab box isn't under significant load you could just remove ELB and use an elastic IP.

Comment: I've just describe the setup I've done https://medium.com/lucjuggery/setup-gitlab-using-aws-services-4f6d314393d#.z1qgjueam

Comment: I used the ELB so it can forward external port 443 towards gitlab 80 using AWS certificate manager. Not sure it's the best way to do this though...

Comment: If you've followed the instructions precisely (especially the Git configuration tweaks) and it doesn't work then you need to change your approach. You haven't posted your config files so we can't check anything. The other approach is to put Nginx in front of Gitlab to terminate TLS and proxy the connection through, it's fairly flexible. Use Let's Encrypt for your certificate if you want it free, I use the client "Acme" / "Acmetool" which is on github. Some hints here on Wordpress which could be helpful  https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5